# load asp.net grid view from asynchronous call

Tags: asp.net, json, gridview, asynchronous

I have a web page which take several minutes to load. The reason for this was this page consist an ASP.NET grid view and data binding for this grid take lots of time.

Each grid view record consist of some complex user details, And it has shown count of items relevant to user preference.
Taking this count according to the user preference is quite expensive operation on the data retrieving stored procedure.
I think this the reason for taking this page long time to load.

As solution for that, I came up with an idea of loading the grid view without the counts of that particular grid record (Remove the counting operation from the data retrieving stored procedure). And update the count label of each grid record with an asynchronous call to the server.

Can anyone have an idea how exactly I can implement this solution with asp.net grid views?

Comment: Is custom paging an option? Where you only load the first, say, 10 records instead of all the records? I do not mean built-in paging either, because that loads the whole data set and then just shows the first page, which would not help your situtation.

Comment: I'm already using custom paging.Data will be load according to the page size option that user selected. i think problem occurs when calculating the counts from the stored procedure. Thats why i thought of remove that counting part from the data loading SP and update the counts using asynchronous call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A web page with a data bound GridView control can take a long time to load. The page is not rendered until all the controls are, and the GridView cannot render before data has been retrieved from the database. So, let’s load the GridView asynchronous and make the page load faster and the perceived speed greater.

This little trick is actually very simple and it involves the built-in client callback feature of ASP.NET. Even though I’m not a big fan of that particular feature, it can be quite handy from time to time. The best part of this is that you don’t have to change much to your existing code.
Web page

On the webpage that hosts the GridView control, you have to make 2 small changes.

**Step 1. Encapsulate the GridView**
The GridView control has to be encapsulated by an HTML control with an id attribute, so that it can be referenced by JavaScript. That is because the GridView does not render when no data is bound to it.

```
<div id="grid">
 <span>Loading...</span>
 <asp:GridView runat="Server" ID="gvAsync" />
</div>
```

**Step 2. Add a JavaScript**
Then a JavaScript is needed to load the rendered and data bound GridView to the HTML control we added in step 1. Place the JavaScript below the GridView’s surrounding div tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function EndGetData(arg)
{
 document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML = arg;
}

setTimeout("<asp:literal runat="server" id="ltCallback" />", 100);
</script>
```

**Code-behind**

In the code-behind file there are three small steps to perform.

**Step 3. Implement ICallbackEventHandler**
We need to implement the interface to turn on the client callback feature.

```
public partial class asyncgridview : System.Web.UI.Page, ICallbackEventHandler
```

**Step 4. Bind the call back reference**
The literal control placed in the JavaScript function in step 2 has to contain the client callback reference. Add the following to the Page_Load.

```
if (!Page.IsCallback)
 ltCallback.Text = ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference(this, "'bindgrid'", "EndGetData", "'asyncgrid'", false);
```

**Step 5. Bind the grid and return the rendered HTML**
To finish the asynchronous loading we have to implement the two methods that are defined by the `ICallbackEventHandler` interface we implemented in step 3. One of the methods binds a `DataTable` to the `GridView` and renders the control. The second returns the rendered HTML to the JavaScript method we defined in step 2.

```
privatestring _Callback;

publicstring GetCallbackResult()
{
 return _Callback;
}

publicvoid RaiseCallbackEvent(string eventArgument)
{
 DataTable table = RetrieveDataTableFromDatabase();
 gvAsync.DataSource = table;
 gvAsync.DataBind();

 using (System.IO.StringWriter sw =new System.IO.StringWriter())
 {
  gvAsync.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(sw));
  _Callback = sw.ToString();
 }
}
```

You can use your present data binding method to bind the `GridView`. The important part is that the `GridView` is data bound before the `RaiseCallbackEvent` method renders the control.

The same technique can be used for all the data control such as the `Repeater, FormView` and `DataList`.

Ref:http://madskristensen.net/post/Asynchronous-GridView-in-5-simple-steps